# Using wait process-id on a bash if-condition returning error code 1 for successful process termination

Tags: bash, shell, wait

I know a little of `bash` return codes on successful/failure conditions, but I was experimenting a little with `wait` on background processes on couple of scripts on `if` condition and I was surprised to see the behavior on the return error codes `0` for success and non-zero for failure cases.

My scripts:-

```
$cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5

$cat bar.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10

$cat experiment.sh 
./foo.sh &
pid1=$!

./bar.sh &
pid2=$!

if  wait $pid1 && wait $pid2
then
    echo "Am getting screwed here!"
else
    echo "Am supposed to be screwed here!"
fi
```

Run the script as  it is and getting the output as `Am getting screwed here!` instead of `Am supposed to be screwed here!`

```
$./experiment.sh
Am getting screwed here!
```

Now modifying the scripts to forcefully return exit codes using `exit` in both `foo.sh` and `bar.sh`

```
$cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
exit 2

$cat bar.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
exit 17
```

And am surprised to see the output as

```
$./experiment.sh
Am supposed to be screwed here!
```

Apologize for the detailed post, but any help appreciated. 
The man page for reference:- http://ss64.com/bash/wait.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct behavior. The exit status of `wait` (when called with a single process ID) is the exit status of the process being waited on. Since at least one of them has a non-zero exit status, the `&&` list fails and the `else` branch is taken.

The rationale is that there is one way (0) for a command to succeed but many ways (any non-zero integer) for it to fail. Don't confuse `bash`'s use of exit statuses with the standard Boolean interpretation of 0 as false and nonzero as true. The shell `if` statement checks if its command succeeds.

Comment: Good explanation! But am still not getting the fact why `if  wait $pid1 && wait $pid2` evaluated to be `if (1)` for the first part of the question when the scripts were returning successfully. You said, `wait` when called with single process returns status of the process being waited on. If that is the case, shouldn't the first part be evaluated to `if (0)` with both `wait`(s) returning successfully?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding exit codes and `if` statements. Make a script with just your `if` statement and replace the `wait` commands with `true`.

Comment: @Mort,@chepner: Bear with me while I get past this :) ! All I am trying to understand is how will `if ( 0 && 0 )` evaluate to a positive condition. Forgive me, if I am missing something basic here.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html "An if/then construct tests whether the exit status of a list of commands is 0 (since 0 means "success" by UNIX convention), ..."

Comment: `&&` is not a boolean operator in the sense you are thinking. The exit status of `cmd1 && cmd2` is 0 (success) if both `cmd1` and `cmd2` have exit statuses of 0. If `cmd1` has a non-zero (failure) exit status, that is the exit status of the compound command (and indeed, `cmd2` does not run at all). If `cmd1` succeeds, then `cmd2` executes and the exit status of the compound command is the exit status of `cmd2`.

Comment: Also, `if ( 0 && )` is not legal syntax. `&&` joins *commands*, not expressions, and `0` is not a command. The equivalent of what you are thinking of would be `if (( 0 && 0 ))`, where `((...))` is a special command whose contents are evaluated as an arithmetic  expression, with an exit status of 0 if the expression has a non-zero value and an exit status of 1 if the expression equals 0. (Don't be tempted into thinking that `(( ... ))` is somehow equivalent to logical NOT, though.)